# Copying row values based on Config file from polars dataframe

Tags: python-polars

I have a dataframe consisting of an `ID`, `Local`, `Entity`, `Field` and `Global` column.

```
# Creating a dictionary with the data
data = {'ID': [4, 4, 4, 4, 4],
        'Local': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'],
        'Field': ['P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T'],   
        'Entity': ['K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O'],
        'Global': ['F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J'],}

# Creating the dataframe
table = pl.DataFrame(data)
print(table)
shape: (5, 5)
┌─────┬───────┬───────┬──────────┬────────┐
│ ID  ┆ Local ┆ Field ┆ Entity   ┆ Global │
│ --- ┆ ---   ┆ ---   ┆ ---      ┆ ---    │
│ i64 ┆ str   ┆ str   ┆ str      ┆ str    │
╞═════╪═══════╪═══════╪══════════╪════════╡
│ 4   ┆ A     ┆ P     ┆ K        ┆ F      │
│ 4   ┆ B     ┆ Q     ┆ L        ┆ G      │
│ 4   ┆ C     ┆ R     ┆ M        ┆ H      │
│ 4   ┆ D     ┆ S     ┆ N        ┆ I      │
│ 4   ┆ E     ┆ T     ┆ O        ┆ J      │
└─────┴───────┴───────┴──────────┴────────┘
```

Within the dataset certain rows need to be copied. For this purpose the following config file is provided with the following information:

```
copying:
- column_name: P
  source_table: K
  destination_table: X
- column_name: S
  source_table: N
  destination_table: W
```

In the config file there is a `column_name` value which refers to the `Field` column, a `source_table` which refers to the given `Entity` and a `destination_table` which should be the future entry in the `Entity` column. The goal is to enrich data based on existing rows (just with other tables).

The solution should look like this:

```
shape: (7, 5)
    ┌─────┬───────┬───────┬──────────┬────────┐
    │ ID  ┆ Local ┆ Field ┆ Entity   ┆ Global │
    │ --- ┆ ---   ┆ ---   ┆ ---      ┆ ---    │
    │ i64 ┆ str   ┆ str   ┆ str      ┆ str    │
    ╞═════╪═══════╪═══════╪══════════╪════════╡
    │ 4   ┆ A     ┆ P     ┆ K        ┆ F      │
    │ 4   ┆ B     ┆ Q     ┆ L        ┆ G      │
    │ 4   ┆ C     ┆ R     ┆ M        ┆ H      │
    │ 4   ┆ D     ┆ S     ┆ N        ┆ I      │
    │ 4   ┆ E     ┆ T     ┆ O        ┆ J      │
    │ 4   ┆ A     ┆ P     ┆ X        ┆ F      │
    │ 4   ┆ D     ┆ S     ┆ W        ┆ I      │
    └─────┴───────┴───────┴──────────┴────────┘
```

The dataset is a polars DataFrame and the config file is loaded as omegaconf.  I tried it with this code:

```
conf.copying = [
    {"column_name": "P", "source_table": "K", "destination_table": "X"},
    {"column_name": "S", "source_table": "N", "destination_table": "W"},
]

# Iterate through the config file
for i in range(len(conf.copying)):
    # Select the rows from the table dataframe that match the column_name and source_table fields in the config
    match_rows = table.filter(
        (pl.col("Field") == conf.copying[i]["column_name"])
        & (pl.col("Entity") == conf.copying[i]["source_table"])
    )
    # Add the column Entities with the destination_table
    match_rows = match_rows.select(
        [
            "ID",
            "Local",
            "Field",
            "Global",
        ]
    )
    # Add the column Entities with the destination_table
    match_rows = match_rows.with_columns(
        pl.lit(conf.copying[i]["destination_table"]).alias("Entity")
    )
    match_rows = match_rows[
        [
            "ID",
            "Local",
            "Field",
            "Entity",
            "Global",
        ]
    ]
    # Append the new rows to the original table dataframe
df_copy = match_rows.vstack(table)
```

However, the data is not copied as expected and added to the existing dataset. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're creating a new `match_rows` each loop iteration. When you `.vstack()` after the loop - `match_rows` will only contain the rows from the last `conf.copying` item.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably better if you extract all of the rows you want in one go.

One possible approach is to build a list of when/then expressions:

```
rules = [
   pl.when(
         (pl.col("Field")  == rule["column_name"]) & 
         (pl.col("Entity") == rule["source_table"]))
     .then(rule["destination_table"])
     .alias("Entity")
   for rule in conf.copying
]
```

You can use `pl.coalesce` and `.drop_nulls()` to remove non-matches.

```
>>> table.with_columns(pl.coalesce(rules)).drop_nulls()
shape: (2, 5)
┌─────┬───────┬───────┬────────┬────────┐
│ ID  | Local | Field | Entity | Global │
│ --- | ---   | ---   | ---    | ---    │
│ i64 | str   | str   | str    | str    │
╞═════╪═══════╪═══════╪════════╪════════╡
│ 4   | A     | P     | X      | F      │
├─────┼───────┼───────┼────────┼────────┤
│ 4   | D     | S     | W      | I      │
└─────┴───────┴───────┴────────┴────────┘
```

This can then be added to the original dataframe.

Another style I've seen is to start with an "empty" when/then to build a `.when().then()` chain e.g.

```
rules = pl.when(False).then(None)
for rule in conf.copying:
   rules = (
      rules.when(
         (pl.col("Field")  == rule["column_name"]) & 
         (pl.col("Entity") == rule["source_table"]))
      .then(rule["destination_table"])
   )
```

```
>>> table.with_columns(rules.alias("Entity")).drop_nulls()
shape: (2, 5)
┌─────┬───────┬───────┬────────┬────────┐
│ ID  | Local | Field | Entity | Global │
│ --- | ---   | ---   | ---    | ---    │
│ i64 | str   | str   | str    | str    │
╞═════╪═══════╪═══════╪════════╪════════╡
│ 4   | A     | P     | X      | F      │
├─────┼───────┼───────┼────────┼────────┤
│ 4   | D     | S     | W      | I      │
└─────┴───────┴───────┴────────┴────────┘
```

I'm not sure if it would make much difference in filtering the rows first and then doing the Entity modification - `pl.any()` could be used if you were to do that:

```
table.filter(
   pl.any([
      (pl.col("Field")  == rule["column_name"]) & 
      (pl.col("Entity") == rule["source_table"])
      for rule in conf.copying
   ])
)
```

```
shape: (2, 5)
┌─────┬───────┬───────┬────────┬────────┐
│ ID  | Local | Field | Entity | Global │
│ --- | ---   | ---   | ---    | ---    │
│ i64 | str   | str   | str    | str    │
╞═════╪═══════╪═══════╪════════╪════════╡
│ 4   | A     | P     | K      | F      │
├─────┼───────┼───────┼────────┼────────┤
│ 4   | D     | S     | N      | I      │
└─────┴───────┴───────┴────────┴────────┘
```